# Why I am not able to show that the List view is clicked?  How to make it possible to show? 

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

In my application, I am using this code to show the List View with Section.
But with this way I am not able to get that which listItem I am going to select. I mean I am not able to see the chang colour while I am going to press on any list item. So how to make it possible for this code:

```
    public static ProgressDialog  m_progressDialog; 
    public Map<String,?> createItem(String title, String caption) {   
        Map<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();   
        item.put(ITEM_TITLE, title);   
       item.put(ITEM_CAPTION, caption);   
        return item;   
    }   

    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {   
        super.onCreate(icicle);  
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // create our list and custom adapter   
        SeparatedListAdapter adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);   
        adapter.addSection("Local documents:", new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "WindowsONE Mobile PK", "WindowsorONE Moldings","Filet for a burger video" }));
        adapter.addSection("Non-local resources:", new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "Launch Photo slideshow link", "Dealer locator link" }));
        adapter.addSection("Send emails:", new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "Send Dealer Locator email", "Send Catalog email","Send install instrucation link" })); 
        //For extra Information in Listview    
        //adapter.addSection("Non-local resources:", new SimpleAdapter(this, security, R.layout.list_complex,   
        //new String[] { ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_CAPTION }, new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title, R.id.list_complex_caption }));        
        ListView list = getListView();
        list.setAdapter(adapter);   
        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this); 
}
```

}

Comment: I think i have to use Customadapter or image adapter. but i got confuse that how to implement it for this static value. So please can anybudy help me to implement it for this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a touch  Listener to your list view and you can show the touch like

```
 ListView.setOnTouchListener(List_onTouch);
```

add a touch listner named List_onTouch

```
    OnTouchListener List_onTouch=new OnTouchListener(){
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0,MotionEvent arg1){
    int iAction=arg1.getAction();
    if(iAction==0){
        ls2.setBackgroundcolor(Color.white);
    }
    else{
 ls2.setBackgroundcolor(Color.orange);     
   }
    return false;
}
};
```

ls2 is your listViewObject and if you click the list it will change your colour to orange

Comment: @iDroidExplorer can u post  your codE?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```